# How to return the content of the <script> element with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to access the content of the script element of a generic website with Selenium.

```
<script>...</script>
```

.

```
url = 'https://unminify.com/'
browser.get(url)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/script[1]')
type_ = [e.get_attribute('type') for e in elements]
text_ = [e.text for e in elements]
```

I get an empty list for text and attribute.

[screenshot from inspecting the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0etna.png)

Comment: Sorry, this is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Although, a few pointers could help. I will keep on searching.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script element and access its contents with the variable of the create element + ".text"

OR

you can put an id for a script element and access its contents with document.getElementById("scriptId").text

(you should change "scriptId" to the id of the script)

```js
var myJs = document.getElementById("myJs");
console.log(myJs.text);
```

```html
<script id="myJs">
alert("This is myJs in action.");
</script>
```

Comment: Please share sample code. Thank you